# How to bind data from parent to child component inside v-for

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

So i have a modal components like this

```
<el-dialog title="Shipping address" :visible.sync="dialogTableVisible">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:300px">Description</th>
    <th style="width:300px">Quantity</th>
    <th style="width:300px">Unit Price</th>
    <th style="width:300px">Amount (Rp. )</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="(item, ind) in invoiceDetails.chargesList" :key="ind" class="h-2">
    <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.qty }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.unitPrice }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.totalPrice }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="(invoiceProduct, k) in invoiceProducts" :key="k">
    <td>
      {{ invoiceProduct.name }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ invoiceProduct.qty }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ invoiceProduct.price }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ invoiceProduct.lineTotal }}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="h-2">
    <td>Subtotal :</td>
    <td>{{ subtotalCharges }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="h-2">
    <td>Tax(10%) :</td>
    <td>{{ taxedCharges }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="h-2">
    <td>Total :</td>
    <td>{{ totalCharges }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and as you can see there are 2 v-for. How do i bind the data from the parent component? the first loop is data that i get from an api, and the second is from a dynamically adding a row

this the parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <PreviewModal
   :dialogTableVisible="dialogTableVisible"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data() {
   return {
     invoiceProducts: []
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

the "invoiceProducts" will be filled with by adding a new row of table and here's the json:

```
"chargesList": [
        {
            "description": "Ocean Freight (Measurement: 5.75 CBM)",
            "qty": "1",
            "unitPrice": "57.5",
            "unitBy": "-",
            "totalPrice": "57.5"
        },
        {
            "description": "Charge1",
            "qty": "1",
            "unitPrice": "10",
            "unitBy": "-",
            "totalPrice": "10"
        },
        {
            "description": "Fast",
            "qty": "1",
            "unitPrice": "20",
            "unitBy": "-",
            "totalPrice": "20"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: With parent component, what component are you referring to?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, What is in this case the parent component? What's in the parent component, What does it have to do with the for loops?

Comment: im trying to fill those v-for with data from the parent element, how to bind them to the modal component

Comment: Should be as simple as using v-bind on the PreviewModal component the same way you're binding 'dialogTableVisible'. Then you can reference that data from a prop in the modal.